# Interface declared as IEnumerable but not usable as such

Tags: c#, casting, ienumerable

I have an IEnumerable interface:

```
public interface IBrands: IEnumerable<Ibrand>
```

And its instanciation:

```
public class Brands: IBrands
{
    public Brands()
    {
        _brandsDic= new Dictionary<int, IBrand>();
    }
}
```

As I used Linq to retreive some data in another class, I had to return some IEnumerable:

```
public IEnumerable<IBrand> GetCarsBrands()
{
    return _carsDic.SelectMany(r => r.Value.Brands).ToList();
}
```

... but would like instead to return directly a IBrands. Would you know how? It complains about the casting of the IBrands in a IEnumerable if I try doing so.

Thanks!

Comment: Check what `SelectMany` returns, it could be an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IBrand>>`.

Comment: Can you show us the exact error message? And what is the declaration of `_carsDic`?

Comment: Error: "Cannot convert expression type 'SystemC.Collections.Generic.List<Interfaces.IBrand>' to return type 'Interfaces.IBrands'"

Answer (score 3):

The IBrands is an `IEnumerable<IBrand>`, but not the other way around. So you can't return an `IEnumerable<IBrand>` as IBrands.

Depending of what Brands actually represents, you could create another instance of Brands.

```
return new Brands(_carsDic.Values);
```